# get all the record that has the specific id through all the Models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question about the rails.

What i want to do is to get all the record through all of the models. that has the specific id it's related to some model's id.

then, show all the records in the show.html

for exp. there is 3 models. User. Post. Note.
Post & Note has record of it's related to User id 1.

```
model User = name:"John", id:1
model Post = title:"post1", user_id:1
model Note = title:"note2", user_id:1
```

in show page (after clicked John at the Index page.)

John's records
-title post1
-title note2

where I'm stcuk is

```
def show
tables = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
models = tables.map{ |table| Object.const_get(table.classify) rescue nil }
```

then, do stuff like models[0].where(:user_id => 1) for each object in models array.
then reflect the result to show/1/

please help,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
def show
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

in view:

```
<% @user.posts.each do |post| %>
 <%= post.title %>
 <% post.notes.each do |note| %>
  <%= note.content %>
 <% end %>
<% end >
```

Good intro for rails - 
http://railsforzombies.org/

Comment: Thank You for the reply.

that is only work for a single model.
i want show from many kind of models.
not only one model.